# Find value of linear transformation for vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Linear transfromation $$ T : R^2 \to R^2 $$ is given by matrix

\begin{split}
A = A(T)_{B,B'} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
-1 & 3\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{split}

For:

\begin{split}
B = {\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} \}} \space \space
B' = {\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} \}}
\end{split}

I had to find transformation matrix in standard basis and I got:

\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{5}{3} & \frac{5}{3} \\
\frac{2}{3} & \frac{5}{3}
\end{bmatrix}

But now I have to find $$ T(\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}) $$ and coordinate vector $ V_B $ and $ T(v)_{B'} $ and I completely struggle to do that. Could someone explain me how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinate vector $v_B$ of $v$ with respect to $B$ is the solution to the equation
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}v_B=v.$$
Note that the columns of the matrix on the left-hand side are the vectors in $B$. Then 
$$T(v)_{B'}=Av_B.$$
You don't need to find the matrix for $T$ with respect to the standard basis.

Comment: Got it, thanks!